# ionic v4(beta) / ionic4 - what is the minimum node/angular version required?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, uicomponents

I am trying to use ionic v4 (Beta) as mentioned in https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cdn in my angular WEB app **(not IOS or Android)**. (ng v1.5.11, node v7.4.0, npm 4.0.5)

I would like to know if there is a **minimum angular/node version requirement** to use ionic v4 UI components.

Although I was able to include the v4 script and get the UI components on my existing app, I am not able to receive events/callbacks from ionic components.

For ex, I could not get ionInput/ionChange events from the ionSearchbar 
https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar/#events

thanks

ionic4, ionicv4

Answer (score 0):

In the [repo](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic). Tt's is from [@ionic/angular4.0.0-beta.17](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/angular) .

And for the ionInput pass the $event object `(ionInput)="search($event)"`.